# Erro minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 4

Tags: android, android-studio

Estou estudando um script e na hora de fazer o build do projeto ele acusa problema de versão, mas só eu estou tendo este problema na minha turma.

```
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="1" android:targetSdkVersion="1" />
```

Error:(5, 5) uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 4 declared in library C:\Projetos\Player\aAALibV4\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-v4\21.0.3\AndroidManifest.xml

Seria a versão Android que usei para construir o projeto o problema?

Comment: Não resolveria mudar a versão para uma mais atual? 22 por exemplo. Tentou copiar o projeto de outro aluno e testar?

Answer (score 1):

Não existe versão "1" do android, por isso a mensagem de erro. Utilze a 19, por exemplo, que é a kitkat.

Coloque: `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />`.

Não se esqueça de atualizar o `build.gradle`.

Comment: Ele teria que executar também um _Clean Project_ não?

Comment: Talvez seja necessário. Ele deve esperar um tempo para que haja um sync do projeto. Uma mensagem é exibida na ferramenta.

Comment: Caso a resposta resolva seu problema, por favor, a marque como correta "ticando" a marca verde abaixo da pontuação da resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Esse erro acontece porque você tá definindo uma versão mínima no seu projeto (versão 1), mas ele tá importando uma biblioteca que precisa de uma versão superior para funcionar (versão 4). No seu caso, é a biblioteca de compatibilidade do Android: `com.android.support:support-v4`.

Você pode corrigir isso modificando o `android:minSdkVersion="1"` para `android:minSdkVersion="16"`, que engloba desde a versão 4.1 do Android (Jellybean) e que cobre cerca de 90% dos dispositivos Android hoje, [de acordo com o próprio Google](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Platform).

A outra configuração é só uma forma de você declarar para qual versão do Android o seu app foi desenvolvido e testado. Quase sempre o recomendado é definir para a última versão (que hoje seria a versão 22). Pra isso é só mudar o `android:targetSdkVersion="1"` para `android:targetSdkVersion="22"`.

No final vai ficar assim:

`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />`